# How do I include multiple add_argument?

Tags: python, json

I have a script that lists, adds, randomises and selects songs from a JSON file. And I am able to access those functions from command line arguments.

What's weird is that if I add `parser.add_argument('add', help='List all songs')`  and try any argument, I get the error `songbook.py: error: the following arguments are required: add`.

Presumably, there's a conflict.

I tried `.append` and `parser.parse_args()` to no avail.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('list', help='List all songs')
args = parser.parse_args()
args: List[str] = sys.argv
```

...

```py
def main():
    if len(args) == 2:
        if sys.argv[1] == "list":
            listSongs()
        elif sys.argv[1] == "add":
            writeToJSON()
        elif sys.argv[1] == "random":
            randomSong()
        else:
            print("Unknown function")
    elif len(args) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1] == "play":
            print("I'll play a song" + str(sys.argv[2]))            
            playSong()
    else:
        print("Give me an argument")
```

Comment: it seems like your first argument should be something like `sub_command_name` and can take the _values_ `"list"` `"add"` or `"random"`, instead of having individual args with those names

Comment: if you then need arguments that are specific to each sub-command then consider using sub-parsers https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: arguments without `-` or `--` are automatically required when you run script and they don't have option `required=False`. If you would define `--add`, `--list`, `--random` then you could use one of them or even all of them. OR you have to define sub command

Comment: BTW: `add_argument('list',...)` doesn't work like `sys.argv[1] == "list"`. It will expect any value which it will assing to variable `args.list` - because it is positional argument, not named argument. So you can always define one `add_argument('command',...)` and later check `if args.command == 'list'` or `if args.command == 'add'`

Answer (score 1):

Arguments without `-` or `--` are positional arguments and they are automatically required when you run script (and they don't have option `required=False` to change it).

Other problem is that positional arguments don't expect exactly words `add`, `list`, `play` but they accept any value and parser assings first value to `args.add`, second value to `args.list`, etc.

If you would define named arguments `--add`, `--list`, `--play` then you could use one of them (or many of them at the same time). But problem can make other parameters for commands - like `filename` for `play` - because all commands would use all the same parameters. So you could run `--list filename` and it would accept it without warning.

You could also use positional argument `cmd` and later check `if args.cmd == 'add'` `if args.cmd == 'list'`, etc. but this has the same problem with shared parameter `filename`.

But there is better method.

It has also `subparsers` which can be executed by defined words `add`,`list`,`play` and every command/subparser may accept different parameters.

```
import argparse

def add_song(args):
    print('[add_song] args:', args)

def list_songs(args):
    print('[list_songs] args:', args)

def play_song(args):
    print('[play_song] args:', args)
    print("I'll play a song:", args.filename)
    
# ----------------

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')

cmd_add  = subparsers.add_parser('add')
cmd_add.set_defaults(func=add_song)

cmd_list = subparsers.add_parser('list')
cmd_list.set_defaults(func=list_songs)

cmd_play = subparsers.add_parser('play')
cmd_play.set_defaults(func=play_song)
cmd_play.add_argument('filename')

#parser.add_argument('-D', '--debug', action='store_true', help='')

args = parser.parse_args(['play', 'hello-world.mp3'])
#args = parser.parse_args(['add'])
#args = parser.parse_args(['list'])
#args = parser.parse_args(['other'])

if args.func:
    args.func(args)
```

Comment: The propositional/optional defintion explains a lot.